# swiftで通知機能付きのtodoを作る方法

Tags: swift

swift初心者です。現在todoアプリを製作しているのですが、設定したイベントの日にちがきたら通知が来るというような機能を追加したいのですが、さっぱり手法が思いつきません。
coredataで設定項目を保存するところまでは実装できたのですが、通知機能の追加方法を教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 3):

`UILocalNotification`を使うのがよいと思います。以下、サンプルです。

```
/// afterSec秒後に通知を出します
func scheduleNotification(alert: String, afterSec: NSTimeInterval) {
    let o = UILocalNotification()
    o.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(afterSec)
    o.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    o.alertBody = alert
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications = [o]
}
```

また、アプリ起動時などに通知設定をONにするようにユーザーに選択させる必要があります。

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .registerUserNotificationSettings(
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))
```